# Does redirecting standard output in a child process do so for the parent process as well?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am studying for an OS exam on Tuesday. In order to prepare, I am attempting to simulate the command line pipe via a C program.

The program is pretty simple. I make a pipe and then fork a child process.

The child process redirects standard output to the write-end of the pipe, closes the file descriptors for the pipe, and then executes a command (`ls`, in this case).

The parent process waits for the child process to exit, redirects standard input to the read-end of the pipe, closes the file descriptors for the pipe, and then executes a command (`grep 'school'`, in this case).

When I execute the command via the command line using `ls | grep 'school'` there is a line that says "school" printed to standard output, which makes sense given that there is a directory in the directory that I am running the program in named that.

When I run the program that I made, I do not receive any error messages, but it does not produce any output.

The only thing I can think of that would prevent this from working is that redirecting standard output in the child process is somehow affecting the output of the parent process's command, but I'm almost positive that that shouldn't be the case.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    int fds[2];
    int pipe_val, close_val, write_val, dup_val, status;
    pid_t pid;
    char *error;

    pipe_val = pipe(fds);
    if (pipe_val) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to prepare pipe.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork a child process.\n");
        return -1;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        dup_val = dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        if (dup_val) {
            error = strerror(errno);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to redirect standard output in child process because %s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
        close_val = close(fds[0]);
        if (close_val) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close read-end of pipe in child process.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close_val = close(fds[1]);
        if (close_val) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close write-end of pipe in child process.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute command in child process.\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        wait(&status);
        dup_val = dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        if (dup_val) {
           error = strerror(errno);
           fprintf(stderr, "Failed to redirect standard input in parent process because %s.\n", error);
            return -1;
        }
        close_val = close(fds[0]);
        if (close_val) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close read-end of the pipe in the parent process.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        close_val = close(fds[1]);
        if (close_val) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close write-end of the pipe in the parent process.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        execl("/bin/grep", "grep", "school", NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute the command in the parent process.\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to close file descriptors in the parent before you wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you haven't included all the necessary headers for the functions you're using. `strerror` requires `<string.h>` and `wait` requires `<sys/wait.h>`.

If you're compiling with gcc, always use `gcc -Wall` and read the warnings. In this case it would have complained about the implicit declaration of `strerror`.

Because `strerror` wasn't declared, the compiler assumes that it returns an `int`, which is wrong. If you are running the program on 64-bit Linux x86, `int` is not even the same *size* as the pointer returned by `strerror`. This becomes a fatal problem when you then pass the result of `strerror` to `fprintf` with a `%s` format, because the pointer has been misinterpreted as an int and then converted back to a pointer, ending up with a bogus value. `fprintf` segfaults and you never see your error message.

Include the right headers and you'll see an error message which will lead you to the next problem you need to fix.